# Use NSMutableURLRequest with JSP

Tags: iphone, objective-c, jsp, post, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm trying to send an HttpRequest from an iPhone app with some parameters. The form is like this:

foo.jsp

```
<form action="/foo" method="post">
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="vendidas" value="25" />
</div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Send!" /></div>
</form>
```

So in the iPhone method when user pushes a botton is:

```
NSString *myRequestString = @"id=3&vendidas=10";
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/"]];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

I guess the problem is to tell the POST that the action is "/foo", but not sure is that. This is my first time doing this and haven't found any help with Google.

Comment: Your "question" isn't so clear. You don't specify an error, you don't ask us something that we can answer. Please edit your question so that there's something specific to answer.

Comment: Do you need to set a user-agent in the HTTP headers?

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question - the URL does not contain path to `foo.jsp`. Try to change `http://localhost:8888/` to `http://localhost:8888/path/to/foo.jsp`.